# Removing everything after the last instance of a specific character

Tags: php

Let's say I have a string, like this:

```
$my_string = 'hello_world-my_name_is-holl';
```

My goal is to run this through a function, and end up with:

```
'hello_world-my_name_is'
```

I want to get rid of everything after the *last* instance of a hyphen.  There can be more than two.  My idea was trying something like this:

```
          $arr = explode("-", $my_string);
          $arr = array_pop($arr);
          $new_name = implode('', $arr);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  What's a good short way of achieving what I'm looking for?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

Comment: Please read the doc.http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php You should remove `$arr=` in the second line. Thats it :)

Comment: @nevermind Ah, I see- once I have that, use substr to just get the first part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is twofold:

first off, `array_pop()` modifies the passed array PLUS returns what it popped off. That means what you are doing here is re-assigning "holl" (a string) to your `$arr` variable and therefore it is no longer an array. That is why the following implode function fails. The second argument needs to be an array, not a string.

Secondly, you'll want to use the hyphen as a glue when putting the array back together into a string. So, the following should work.

```
$my_string = 'hello_world-my_name_is-holl';

$arr = explode("-", $my_string);
$arr2 = array_pop($arr);
$new_name = implode('-', $arr);

echo $new_name;
```

As you can see, I assigned the popped-off "holl" to a new variable (in case you need it), but then imploded the original, but modified array `$arr`.

Comment: Both of those things I did not understand.  I have applied this in my code and it works like a charm.  Thank you!